# Django, DataWizard, SessionWizardView get current user

Tags: django, formwizard

I am creating a series of forms, processed via Django's form wizard, however, the forms consist of many dropdown boxes, the content of which depend on the current user and therefore, I need to pass the User as a kewword argument.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
class ViewDataWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name="wizards/data/view_data.html"
    def done(self, form_list,**kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
        return render_to_response('wizards/data/view_data_done.html',{'form_data':form_data})
```

However, I am seeking to produce this:

```
class ViewDataWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name="wizards/data/view_data.html"
    def get_form_kwargs(self, step):
        if step == 0:
            return {'user':<USEROBJECT>}
        else:
            return {}
    def done(self, form_list,**kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
        return render_to_response('wizards/data/view_data_done.html',{'form_data':form_data})
```

Where in the second example above, I need to substitute USEROBJECT with the current user, to seed the series of forms.

Am I missing something really obvious? Traditionally I would get user from `request.user` in a given view, however, this seems elusive in the forms wizard process...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `request` object from `self`.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, step):
    if step == 0:
        return {'user': self.request.user}
    else:
        return {}
```